# Why is volume charge density defined for conducting objects?

Tags: electrostatics, charge, conductors

I recently read a derivation of electric field due to a solid conducting sphere which also included a term volume charge density. We know that charge on a conductor resides on the surface. My question is that if charge on a conducting sphere resides on the surface then why do we define volume charge density for conducting sphere and for that matter matter any object which is conducting?

Comment: a conductor body doesn't have volume charge density, it must be derivation for nonconducting solid sphere

Comment: I checked it again and it is a conducting sphere.

Comment: Read where? Which page?

Comment: I realised that it is written "Electric field due to charged spherical shell or solid conducting sphere". I thought these were seperate cases but they're not. Thank you for your time.